# Git: How should I get changes of a branch and a branch of a branch into master?

Tags: git, git-svn

I branched `master` to make a `feature`.  Then I branched that `feature` to make a `feature2`.  Now I want to get *all* the changes into `master`.  How do I do that?  I was thinking I'd do this:

```
git rebase master feature #to make sure history is linear
git rebase feature feature2 #to make sure history is linear
git checkout feature
git merge feature2 --ff-only
git checkout master
git merge feature --ff-only
```

Would this do the trick?  I want my history to be linear because I'm using git-svn and I heard non-linear history messes it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will get you where you want to go. You can omit the merging of feature2 -> feature and merge feature2 directly into master, if you want a slightly simpler set of commands.

```
git rebase feature feature2    # Ensure that all feature changes are
                               # included in feature2

git rebase master feature2     # Create a linear history
git checkout master
git merge feature2             # Merge feature2, which contains feature,
                               # into master
```